# Limit of series $4\left( \frac {1}{8}+\frac {1}{12}\right) +6\left( \frac {1}{24}+\frac {1}{36}\right) +\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find this serie 
$4\left( \dfrac {1}{8}+\dfrac {1}{12}\right) +6\left( \dfrac {1}{24}+\dfrac {1}{36}\right) +8\left( \dfrac {1}{64}+\dfrac {1}{96}\right) +\ldots $
I think it's telescopic, isn't it?

Comment: write what telescopic you think it is...

Comment: What's the formula for the general term?  It's not obvious to me how the series continues.

Comment: Please do not use displaystyle MathJax in your title (\dfrac) and do not make a title with only MathJax in it.

Comment: It looks like two simple geometric series, interleaved.

Answer (score 5):

The $n$th term appears to be $$2(n+1)\left(\frac1{2^{n+1}(n+1)}+ \frac1{2^{n}3(n+1)}\right).$$

Canceling factors of $2(n+1)$, we can rewrite the $n$th term as

$$\left(\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}{3}}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{2^n3} + \frac{2}{2^{n}{3}}\right) = \left(\frac{5}{2^n3}\right)$$

So the series is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac53 \cdot 2^{-n} = \frac53\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = \frac53.$$

Answer (score 1):

The terms in this sum seem to be 
$$
2n\left( \dfrac {1}{2^{n-1}2n}+\dfrac {1}{3\cdot2^{n-2}2n}\right)
=
\dfrac {5}{6}\frac1{2^{n-2}}
$$
starting from $n=2$.

This is a geometric series and easy to sum.

Comment: There's a mistake. The second term should have $2^{n-2}$..

Comment: @user99454, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

multiple the numbers before parantheses then it's formula for the general will be obtained
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^{n-1}})$$
and it's equal to following geometric serie:
$$\frac{5}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{10}{6}$$